# What happens if I spawn inside someone else in DayZ?

Tags: dayz-2012

Whenever I leave a game server in *DayZ*, my current location is saved so that I spawn there when I log in again.

What happens if someone is standing in that exact spot? Would I get spawned somewhere else? Would I just spawn next to the guy?

Comment: Are you able to rephrase your first sentence? It's very hard to understand, as I can't tell the main point you are trying to convey in this one sentence.

Answer (score 7):

It would be pretty hard for someone to randomly be in the exact same spot as where you logged out, but in the case it did happen the person would be pushed over a bit and you would spawn in your normal place so no errors occur. Good luck with those zombies.

Comment: @Michael if you want to thank somebody for answering you should upvote and accept their answer. The buttons are to the left of the answer.

Comment: It's fine. I'm just here to help.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a team and one of my friends was de-syncing badly so he disconnected while we waited for him to rejoin.  When he reconnect he died instantly right next to a fellow survivor.  I am assuming it was because he spawned on-top of another player however it may have been a server glitch.